# Unit testing mvc login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-view-controller, authentication

I've been creating a unit test, but seemed to failed. Can any one help me in creating a unit  test for this controller?

I've already tried various ways.

```
    public class logInController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(logInModel model)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int match = 0;

                sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);

                sqlComm = new SqlCommand("spLogin", sqlConn);
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", model.Username);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", model.Password);

                SqlParameter userMatch = new SqlParameter("@userMatch", SqlDbType.Int);
                userMatch.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add(userMatch);

                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                match = Convert.ToInt32(sqlComm.Parameters["@userMatch"].Value);
                sqlConn.Close();

                if (match != 0)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false); 
                    return RedirectToAction("index","home");
                }
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

---

at this time i'm trying this one.

```
public void LoginTest() 
        {
            var controller = new logInController();
            var loginmodel = new logInModel
            {
                Username = "arwinortiz",
                Password = "123456"
            };
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginmodel.Username, false);
            var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Index(loginmodel);
            result.RouteValues["action"].Equals("index");
            result.RouteValues["controller"].Equals("home");
            Assert.AreEqual("index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("home", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
        }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, we are not going to build the entire model for you.

Comment: You need to abstract the db stuff out of the controller. Just saying...

Answer (score 1):

First you need to abstract your database and Forms authentication calls out into their own concerns/interfaces so that they can be mocked. (Shame.....Shame....)

```
public interface IAuthenticationService {
    bool Authenticate(string username, string password);   
}

public interface IFormsAuthenticationService {
    void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);
    void SignOut();
}
```

with that done your controller can be refactored down to

```
public class logInController : Controller {
    private IAuthenticationService authenticator;
    private IFormsAuthenticationService formsAuthentication;

    public MvcTestsController(IAuthenticationService userAuthentication, IFormsAuthenticationService formsAuthentication) {
        this.authenticator = userAuthentication;
        this.formsAuthentication = formsAuthentication;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(logInModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            bool match = authenticator.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password);
            if (match) {
                formsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            } else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Next we write our unit test for login.

**Note:** I am using [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) for mocking dependencies and [FluentAssertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/) for asserting results.

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoginTest() {
    //Arrange
    var loginmodel = new logInModel {
        Username = "arwinortiz",
        Password = "123456"
    };
    var mockAuthenticator = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>();
    mockAuthenticator
            .Setup(x => x.Authenticate(It.Is<string>(s => s == loginmodel.Username), It.Is<string>(s => s == loginmodel.Password)))
            .Returns(true);
    var mockFormsAuthentication = new Mock<IFormsAuthenticationService>();

    bool isAuthCookieSet = false;
    mockFormsAuthentication
        .Setup(x => x.SetAuthCookie(It.Is<string>(s => s == loginmodel.Username), It.IsAny<bool>()))
        .Callback(() => { isAuthCookieSet = true; });

    var controller = new logInController(mockAuthenticator.Object, mockFormsAuthentication.Object);

    //Act
    var result = (System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Index(loginmodel);

    //Assert (using FluentAssertions)
    result.Should().NotBeNull(because: "the result should have redirected for entered user ");
    result.RouteValues["action"].ShouldBeEquivalentTo("index", because: "the redirection was to home.index action");
    result.RouteValues["controller"].ShouldBeEquivalentTo("home", because: "the result should redirect to home controller");
    isAuthCookieSet.Should().BeTrue(because: "auth cookie is set if the user was authenticated");
}
```